# I was trying to detach the external hard disk, then a error massage appear (explorer.exe)

Tags: windows-xp

I was trying to detach the external hard disk, then a error massage appear (explorer.exe ) Is there any reason why explorer.exe is holding on to my external hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

Did you double-click on "Safely remove hardware" in the systray in the lower right-hand corner? You should safely remove it before unplugging it.

[image]